# Remote Machine IP disappears when entering Play Mode (Unity/Hololens)

Tags: unity-game-engine, deployment, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm working with an XR Unity project (2019.4.26f1) and I'm trying to deploy it on the HoloLens 2. I've managed to build the project and to run it in the HL from Visual Studio by cable but I need to be able to see the app in the HL when I enter on the Play Mode in Unity.

I've followed some tutorials like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-play-mode?tabs=winxr) and I can do every step but when I get to the step of writing the IP in the Windows Mixed Reality window, a problem appears. When I hit play to go on Play mode, the IP disappears, and I receive an error because the Remote Machine Address is not set. Why is this happening?

I have something like this, with the IP of the HoloLens in the field, the HL are ON and with the HoloRemoting app running. I can access this IP by browser and see that the status is "Connected" and see Live footage of the Lens camera.

[image]

However, when I hit "Play", the IP disappears and I get this error.

> Atempting to initiate remoting connection with no valid machine name
> set. UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_PlayModeStateChanged
> (UnityEditor.PlayModeStateChange)

[image: Unity screenshot with the error message 'Atempting to initiate remoting connection with no valid machine name set']

Answer (score 2):

Due to potential compatibility issues, it is highly recommended to upgrade your Unity version to 2020.3.31f1 with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin. You may refer to the document on [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20203-lts-recommended)